# Unable to use video in custom-header

Tags: wordpress, custom-headers

Under theme customisation, I'm unable to set a video as the `Header Media`. This theme is being created from scratch so I've currently only got the following files: header.php, footer.php, functions.php, sidebar.php, index.php

I've tried setting video to true in the theme support section for wordpress. I've tried copying the implementation in the twentyseventeen theme.
I've tried different combination of parameters in the custom-header theme support function.

functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'video' => true,
) );
```

header.php:

```
<?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
```

Wordpress is currently giving me the following error:

> "This theme doesn’t support video headers on this page. Navigate to
>   the front page or another page that supports video headers."

Comment: In which page you are testing video header? By default, videos are only loaded on the front page. In other page, fallback image is displayed instead of video.

Comment: I am looking at the front page.

Answer (score 0):

In my functions.php I was loading jQuery like the following:

```
    wp_enqueue_script('wptheme-jquery-js-cdn', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js');
```

This caused jQuery to load first. To solve this, I forced it to be loaded in the footer.

```
    wp_enqueue_script('wptheme-jquery-js-cdn', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array(), '', true);
```

This is also better practice to stop it blocking rendering.